# After Lion upgrade, external monitor sometimes shows color noise

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, displayport

Hardware:

- Early 2011 (pre Thunderbolt) MBP 15"
- Apple Mini Display to DVI adapter
- Dell 2408WFP (using included DVI cable)

Before upgrading from Snow Leopard to Lion, I did not have this problem. None of the hardware has changed.

The problem is that sometimes, briefly after connecting my external monitor (sometimes as quickly as 1 minute, sometimes as long as 5), the picture starts displaying color noise. From the time that I connect the monitor until the color noise, the picture displays fine and I can put applications there and use them. During the noise, I can even drag an app over to that screen and back (hidden behind the noise, not on top of it).

I've tried using a friend's Mini-Display to DVI adapter, and that didn't fix it.

What's really, really annoying is that it's temporary. I come to work in the morning and connect the monitor after logging in. Then I may have to disconnect and reconnect it 3-4 times before the noise doesn't come back. I also occasionally see a little bit of noise in the picture in the minutes before the whole screen becomes noise.

I haven't been able to find any forum posts/etc of anyone else having the same issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Take your MBP into an Apple Store (not an Apple authorized service repair shop) and get them to run some diagnostics. If the unit is found faulty, they will fix it for you.

Comment: I have this problem. I'm almost certain it's down to the connection for the adapter on the laptop. It only happens when I plug it in, after moving it slightly the problem goes away but when I'm using a VGA adapter I get a very red version of my desktop and when I'm using my DVI it's goes a bit mental. Nothing you can do really but live with it, get a new mac or (if you can) get the Mini DisplayPort fixed. EDIT: Saying this, I got this before my upgrade to Lion...

Comment: I don't understand why this item is marked closed, this item is very useful as more people are noticing that this original problem is a Lion bug and not a hardware problem even though there are non-lion reasons why these kind of symptoms can happen.  This is related to a crashing bug in Lion that can be resolved by deleting the external display preferences.

Comment: @jdkoftinoff it sounds like you're using a very specific reference... can you link to it? I'd love to be able to try that...

Comment: Here is a video someone else made which matches my experiences: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ueoS583PuJA and their reference on the apple forums: https://discussions.apple.com/message/16881510#16881510 - there are other similar postings

Comment: Ah, that does not match my experience. I actually get full-screen snow.

Comment: Too bad this was closed; I got the same issue. Thanks @jdkoftinoff for posting a solution.

Comment: FWIW I have the same problem with a Late 2012 15" MBP Retina with Mountain Lion.

Comment: @SteveFallows I have since switched to a different monitor (from Acer) and don't have the problem at all. I'm guessing this was some sort of driver mismatch or issue with that specific model/line from Dell.